# How can I summ tuple

Tags: python, function, operators

I Have to code the game " the accoun is good" 
And for it, I have only it :

```
from random import *

# etat = nombre obtenu

randint(0, 20)

nombre1 = randint(0, 200)
nombre2 = randint(0, 200)
nombre3 = randint(0, 200)
nombre4 = randint(0, 200)
nombre5 = randint(0, 200)
nombre6 = randint(0, 200)

nombre_final = randint(1, 1000)

état_initial = (nombre1, nombre2, nombre3, nombre4, nombre5, nombre6)

etat_final = nombre_final


etat = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)


def gagner(etat):
    return etat == etat_final
```

My final goal will be to have the "nombre_final" thanks my 6 random number, but for me it is very far yet.

I just want create all my operator and I would like know how I can return 1 number who will be the result of tuples.

For exemple 
number 1+ number 2 = my new number

For my operators , I did it but I know it's bad :

```
def gagner(etat):
    return etat == etat_final
def addition1(etat):
    return((((etat[0])) + (etat[1])))

def addition2(etat):
    return((etat[0] + etat[2]))


def addition3(etat):
    return((etat[0] + etat[3]))

def addition4(etat):
    return((etat[0] + etat[4]))

I did it for all, and for substraction, multiplication, division...


Thanks in advance !!!!!
```

Comment: Something like sum((2,4,5,))?  In other words, sum(tuple).  Is that your question?

Answer (score 1):

I assume english is not your first language. But python has a sum function that takes a tuple as an argument and returns the sum of its members.

```
tuple=(1,2,3,4)

x=sum(tuple)

print x
```

Comment: Hmm that's not rly what I want,  I want for example a function to sum  1 +2  or 1+3  or 1+4  or 2+3  or 2+4  or 3+4

Comment: ```def addfunc(index1,index2,tuple): return tuple[index1]+tuple[index2] 

```